# negative value with IRanges

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm using the **Gviz library from Bioconductor**, I'm trying to plot ideograms which are technically graphed from left to right, but our data have some negative width indicating that the plot should be from right to left. **How can I input negative values for the width with IRanges?**

Here is the piece of code we're working with:

```
library(Gviz)
library(IRanges)
gen <- "mm9"
chr <- "chr1"

itrack <- IdeogramTrack(genome = gen, chromosome = chr)
gtrack <- GenomeAxisTrack()

dat <- read.delim("C:/R/mydata.TXT", header = FALSE, sep ="\t")
s <- dat[[2]]
e <- dat[[3]]
l <- dat[[4]]

annot1 = IRanges(start = s, width = l)
Error.Call2("solve_user_SEW0", start, end, width, PACKAGE = "IRanges") : 
solving row 1: negative widths are not allowed

# Those logical following commands work well if no negative integer is passed to IRanges
atrack <- AnnotationTrack (annot1, chromosome = chr, genome = gen, name = "foo") 
plotTracks (list(itrack, gtrack, atrack))
```

Thanks :))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error message says, IRanges can't have negative width -- the 'start' is always left-most. Perhaps using a GRanges object with `strand="-"`?